# shortest path in hash map

Tags: hash, dictionary, graph-theory

The following is a data set I have stored in a hash map, and I have to find the shortest path between two values.

```
9244, 4322, 4886, 5989, 8598, 9979, 1447, 9657
8598, 6752, 7146, 1951, 660, 1447, 7779
568, 1951, 4886, 2570, 9026, 9489, 7779
6752, 3424, 1977, 4746, 9657
77
```

The key value of the hash map is the first value of each line, the rest are the supposed "friends" of 9244 (same in each case).

i have saved in hash table in this format: `hashmap(key, array)`, where:

- key is e.g. 9244
- array then holds [ 4322, 4886, 5989, 8598, 9979, 1447, 9657 ]

How to find shortest path between two keys?

Comment: Could you add some fullstops and capital letters so that I can distinguish the sentences from each other? I have not grasped what you are asking for... :-O

Comment: I tried, not sure if I made it better or worse.

Comment: How in the world is it possible to determine "shortest path" between two integers?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, those integers are nodes in a graph and s?he uses the hash table as an adjacency list of this graph. So 9244 has neighbours 4322, 4866, etc. But as I see it I doubt this is the full adjacency list.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, you're talking about the [Shortest Path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path) with a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

- Starting with an integer, get the array of integers it maps to.
- Each of those integers is the key to a new array.
- Follow those paths and find the shortest one.

If you do a google search, and look on the Wikipedia page, you'll be able to find plenty of code samples and algorithms that will help you.

As Peter Smit mentioned, the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm is a common one for this problem.  Others include [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm. You can build a graph out of this first and then follow the pseudocode on the wikipedia page.

Comment: For A* you need a good heuristic which estimates how far away from the goal you are. In a general graph this is a bit hard to do. I'd rather suggest Dijkstra's algorithm in this case.